# Skip host while nmap is running

Tags: nmap

Is there a way to skip a host while it is being scanned. I am providing a list of hosts to nmap and while it is scanning from that list, I would like to skip one host because the scripts keep running on that host hence delaying my scan. Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just remove it from the list?

Comment: That’s what I will do eventually. I was just thinking if there is a solution which will allow me to make changes during runtime. Thank you for your comment through.

Answer (score 2):

There is not a way during runtime to stop scanning a host. However, you can [impose time limits](https://nmap.org/book/man-performance.html) on how long Nmap spends on a particular host. The `--host-timeout` option will cause Nmap to drop all results and stop scanning a target when the timeout expires. Unfortunately, this means all that work is lost. But there is a better way, if NSE scripts are slowing you down.

Nmap 7.30 added the `--script-timeout` option, which puts a time limit on *each* NSE script that runs against a target. Any script that exceeds the time limit will be terminated and will produce no output, but any other scripts will be allowed to run. No port scan, OS detection, or traceroute data will be lost.

Your last option if NSE is taking too long is to find out which script is causing the problem. Most NSE scripts are designed to run quickly; even most of the brute-force password guessing scripts enforce a 10-minute time limit. But sometimes there are bugs, and other times you may select a script with an intentionally long run time. In debug mode (`-d` or press <kbd>d</kbd> during runtime), printing a status line (by pressing any key during execution) will show a list of running scripts when there are 5 or fewer running. At debug level 2 (`-dd` or press <kbd>d</kbd> twice), a full stack trace of each running script thread is produced, which can help Nmap developers debug delays. If you suspect a misbehaving script, you can [file a bug report on Github](http://issues.nmap.org/) or send it to dev@nmap.org.

Comment: As of versions 7.91 and 7.92, nmap's `--script-timeout` parameter is broken and being ignored - https://github.com/nmap/nmap/issues/2297

Answer (score 1):

nmap has a host timeout option which will give up on any host that takes longer than the provided value. So, the below option would give up on any host that takes longer than 10 minutes. You can read more about the various timing related options [here](https://nmap.org/book/man-performance.html).

```
nmap --host-timeout 10m
```